# Using logical expression in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, where-clause

I am trying to write a Python command that includes a logical query. I have series of tables and layers and would like to run a command on them when two shared variables have the same values. I created a list of those tables and layers:

```
pattern = '*Assess*.dbf'
files = []
tables = []
layernames = []
## create the loop element
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(inputFolder):
    # append shapefile path to list
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern):
        files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

tables = arcpy.ListTables()

for file in files:
    names.append("\"TOWN_ID\" = " + str(int(os.path.basename(file).rstrip(os.path.splitext(file)[1])[1:4])))
    layernames.append(str(int(os.path.basename(file).rstrip(os.path.splitext(file)[1])[1:4])))
```

The code is as followed:

```
for layername, table in zip(layernames, tables):
    #print layername
    #print table
    #CF_QueryTool = "C:\\ArcGIS_Temp\\parcel_mosaic\\land_parcels_mosaic.gdb\\cf_QueryTool"
    tablelist = [table, "TaxParcels_Layer.{}".format(layername)]
    whereclause = "TaxParcels_Layer.{}.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID".format(layername)
    print tablelist
    print whereclause
    arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tablelist, "QueryTable.{}".format(layername), "ADD_VIRTUAL_KEY_FIELD", "", "" ,whereclause)
    print "QueryTable.{} created".format(layername)
```

My where clause translates to "TaxParcels_Layer.1.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID".

The problem is, apparently there is something wrong with my `WHERE`-clause which made me wonder if I can actually use something like `table.locid` using a list of tables. Let me know if I'm making a mistake here.

Comment: What does the output show for the contents of the (renamed) `whereclause` variable?  Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: It shows: "TaxParcels_Layer.1.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID"

Comment: So the ".1." part is wrong, right? Pay closer attention to the contents of `layername`.

Comment: Why would it be wrong? layernames is ['1', '37']. I want it to iterate so I used the format method. Isn't that correct?

Comment: A numeric string is not a valid table or field name.

Comment: Even mixed with letters? the table name here would be "TaxParcels_Layer.1"

Comment: Periods are not valid in table names either, only to separate database from schema from table from column in databases. A valid SQL identifier is [a-zA-Z](a-zA-Z0-9_)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this now. I'm quite new to python. Post this as an answer so that I can accept it